# express/nodejs: stop duplicates in post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What should I do to stop the post request from posting new object if the object already exists?
I have pasted my code and json object. I have tried `next();` but it doesnt work and a duplicate object with some other id is created no matter what. I am using `before`  beforePostTransaction function to check if the product already exists. The request contains the id and the store id of the

index.js

```
const Transaction = require('./transactions/TransactionModel');
const TransactionCTL = require('./transactions/TransactionController');
Transaction.before('post', TransactionCTL.beforePostTransaction);
Transaction.register(router, '/transactions');
```

TransactionController.js

```
const beforePostTransaction = (req, res, next) => {
var id = req.body.id;
Transaction.findById(
    id, 
    (err, data)=>{
        if (!data){
            next();
        }
        else{

            var store = data.store;
            store = JSON.stringify(store);
            store = store.replace(/\"/g, "");
            if(store !== req.body.store){ //update the whole object
                next();
            }
            else{
            //do what?
            }

        }
    });
    res.sendStatus(409);
}
```

json object

```
[{
    "_id": "596db06849822a13c97ba3f9",
    "store": "596b088131ea400490897c50"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your model. But if it is mongoose you can use method

```
.findOneAndUpdate(query,
        update,
        {upsert: true},
        function (error, result) {
          if (!error) { //if you need to do something else
          }
        });
```

Where update is your object. It will create new item if it not exist and update it if it exist.

Comment: And i dont want to update it. I want to overwrite it completely with the new object.

Comment: According to your code ID is the only thing with can help you to identify if this already was inserted. So update in this case mean overwrite store param and keep id(it's same anyway). If you don't care about id's and need only unique store values just use query with store, not id.